# Request being intercepted twice by Servlet Filter

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I have a project that uses JSF . I have written a filter that intercepts every request for 2 purposes :
1) change session id with each request , for security reasons
2) check whether a user is logged in , else redirect to login page, again for security reason so that unless properly authenticated, no one sees "internal" pages

A Simplistic code of my LoginFilter (ofcourse I have omitted the session id change and redirection parts to keep things simple)

```
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        String reqUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();

        System.out.println("reqUrl : " + reqUrl);

        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession();
        System.out.println("session obj : " + session);

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        System.out.println("reqUrl AFTER :: " + reqUrl);
    }
}
```

When I log in , the `doFilter` method of Filter is called once for the url of the page that comes next after login screen, intercepting request.

Since I am tracing (`System.out.println`) urls that pass through the filter, 
this is what I get in console

```
reqUrl : http://localhost:8082/meqms/module/voting/mainframe.jsf
session obj : org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@396df0c7
reqUrl AFTER :: http://localhost:8082/meqms/module/voting/mainframe.jsf
```

However if I refresh the page now , 
the request gets intercepted twice.

and console gets new entries like

```
reqUrl : http://localhost:8082/meqms/module/voting/mainframe.jsf
session obj : org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@396df0c7
reqUrl AFTER :: http://localhost:8082/meqms/module/voting/mainframe.jsf
reqUrl : http://localhost:8082/meqms/module/voting/mainframe.jsf
session obj : org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@396df0c7
BROKER_MSTR_BEAN
reqUrl AFTER :: http://localhost:8082/meqms/module/voting/mainframe.jsf
```

I am not understanding whats happening here. 
However one thing I did notice is the resource being loaded , i.e , `mainframe.xhtml` calls a JSF bean method on page load 
which prints BROKER_MSTR_BEAN

This printing comes in second interception , not the first one . which leads me to believe the page `mainframe.xhtml` gets loaded only on second "interception" (of filter).

If thats the case, why is the first call at all ?? 
whats happening here . why a resource would be requested twice (and hence intercepted twice by filter ?)

=============== EDIT ==========================
we have 2 mainframe.xhtml here . one includes the other

main one :

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/include/template/page-template.xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="page-content">
        <ui:param name="currentContentDescriptor"
            value="#{applicationController.currentContextDescriptor}" />
        <ui:decorate
            template="/WEB-INF/include/template/plain_container.xhtml">

            example template
            <ui:define name="example">
                <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/include/ksecurity_vote/mainframe.xhtml" />
            </ui:define>
        </ui:decorate>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

the one being included :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<h:form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:mobi="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/mobile/component">


    <div style="visibility: hidden;">
        <h:outputText value="#{brokerMstr.onpageload}" />
    </div>
</h:form>
```

BrokerMstrBean.java

```
public class BrokerMstrBean extends GenericDaoImpl<BrokerMstr> implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String onpageload;

    public void setOnpageload(String onpageload) {
        this.onpageload = onpageload;
    }

    public String getOnpageload() {
        System.out.println("Brokermstrbean");
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        Object s = req.getParameter("status");
        if (s == null) {
            s = req.getAttribute("status1");
            System.out.println(" status " + s);
        }
        if (s != null) {
            if ((s.equals("0")) || (s.equals("1"))) {
                setValidation_popup(false);

            }
        }

        return onpageload;
    }
```

I am not very good in jsf . This project was made by someone else. Can you please help

Comment: Please create a [mcve] as requested by [ask]

Comment: I have given a MCV example now . isn't it? can you or someone answer now please ?

Comment: No it is not an [mcve] in my opinion. `GenericDaoImpl<BrokerMstr>` are missing and I doubt you need them for an [mcve]. Is using an include relevant for the problem? I doubt it, please put it in one xhtml file. Is all the logic in `getOnPageload()` relevant? If not, remove it. etc...

Comment: Also debug if the browser actually sends two requests. Try using a phaselistener to debug this server side

Comment: Further, it's lacking completeness because you have not included relevant parts from `web.xml`, particularly regarding filters.